# SQL Error When Running My "Find All Unused Packages" in SCCM 2007 Report Console

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql, sccm, ssrs, sccm-2007

SQL Error When Running My "Find All Unused Packages" in SCCM 2007 Report Console
Asked by: the_ratzenator I am trying to run an SCCM 2007 Report to find all unused Pacakges in my environment and I keep getting this error:

> An error occurred when the report was run. The details are as follows:
>   The SELECT permission was denied on the object
>   'vPkgStatusSummaryDistPts', database 'SMS_PAK', schema 'dbo'. Error
>   Number: -2147217911  Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server 
>   Native Error: 229

Here is the SQL code I got from here: http://blog.itminutes.net/?p=781

```
SELECT PackageID, Name, Version, Manufacturer, Language, Description, 
PkgSourcePath AS [Source Path], LastRefreshTime,
(SELECT COUNT(PkgID) FROM vPkgStatusSummaryDistPts WHERE PkgID = v_Package.PackageID) AS [No of DP]
FROM v_Package
WHERE 
PackageID NOT IN (SELECT PackageID FROM v_Advertisement) AND 
PackageID NOT IN (SELECT ReferencePackageID FROM v_TaskSequenceReferencesInfo) AND 
PackageType = 0
ORDER BY Name
```

This runs in SQL Server Management Studio, but not in my SCCM 2007 Reporting console.

I checked and the "webreport_approle" does exist.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Problem resolved below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it. Here was the fix:

GRANT SELECT
ON vPkgStatusSummaryDistPts
TO webreport_approle